# how to make request to same page in php using $GET?

Tags: php

I have no idea how to make request to the same page using $GET. Please help me out

[image]

Comment: Hi, Tej. Please read [ask]

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Its $_GET  not $GET. If no action provided it will be in same page. Check $_GET variable with its existence and use print_r to see all data. Share your html and php.

Comment: ..but you've not even tried...

Answer (score 0):

using $_GET is easy, just append the query string

```
<a href="thispage.php?someParam=someValue">send get request</a>
```

To retrieve:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['someParam'])){
    echo $_GET['someParam']; // will echo "someValue";
}
?>
```

See here for details: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php